# Possible to Auto Open file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clearcase

I currently use the following cleartool command using Visual Studios External tool interface:

Command: `\installationpath\cleartool.exe`
Arguments: `annotate -nheader $(ItemPath)`
Initial directory: `$(ItemDir)`

I do use the output window.  Which will let that command print out the location of the .ann file it produces.  I'm wondering if there is a way for Visual studio to auto open that produced file?

In this case its not a huge hardship to copy the location and open the file.  I'm just always looking for ways to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Using just *one* external tool, you wouldn't be able to execute `cleartool`, *and* to open a file (generated from the `cleartool` command).

[image: external tool]

You can open a file from a Visual Studio External Tool as [explained here](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2009/03/02/Visual+Studio+Tip+Of+The+Day+Open+Filesfolders+In+Windows+Explorer.aspx), but that wouldn't execute `cleartool`.

So I would recommend executing a script (`.bat`, `.cmd`, `.vbs`) in order to:

- do the `cleartool` command you want
- open the generated file.

You would pass to this script no only $(ItemPath), but also, depending on where it is generated, `$(ItemDir)`, or `$(ProjectDir)`, or `$(SolutionDir)`, or `$(TargetDir)`.

Comment: I was hoping to open the file into the same instance of Visual Studio.  Kinda like feed the output of the cleartool command back into Visual Studio which might be asking for too much.  From reading the provided link that seems like it might give me the option to open the file which I think in my case would launch a new copy of Visual Studio or possibly another tool.(I do appreciate the idea and opening the file in another instance might be as close as I can get)